Why passing an object do not throw an error while passing object literal throws error?
I have two types Person and User. User has an extra key as id. There is a function called printPerson. It expects a person argument which has to be of type Person
Here is the code
type Person={
    name:string;
    age: number;
}

type User={
    name:string;
    age:number;
    id:number;
}

function printPerson(person:Person){
    console.log(person.name,person.age);
}

Now i try to call the function two times. Once by passing an object as an argument and once by passing an object literal
const user:User={
    name:'Ajay',
    age:23,
    id:1
}

printPerson(user);    //throws no error

printPerson({name:"Ajay", age:23, id:1})  //Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'Person'


I read that typescript is a structurally types language hence the error was not thrown in the first case. But I am unable to understand since the structure of the data is same in both the case, only difference is how the argument is passed. What is the logic behind such a behaviour?
Please guide me to understand this behaviour of typescript

What is your question? The error message regarding the object literal seems very clear to me. Your User type satisfies the contract for Person which is why it is allowed

My question is that in both the case the same data is being passed in the argument, but in one case it throws error and in other it does not.What is the reason for such a behaviour?

That doesn't sound like a question.

The best explanation I've seen is that excess properties in an object literal are unreachable from TypeScript's point of view. If we take your code, the object literal {name:"Ajay", age:23, id:1} is being passed to a parameter that does not use id. Thus, the id property is entirely useless—it certainly can't be used anywhere outside the function either since it's an object literal that was passed directly to the function call. TypeScript sees this as a mistake.
On the other hand, if you simply just assign the literal to a variable—it doesn't even have to have a type annotation—it's okay.
    const obj = {{name:"Ajay", age:23, id:1}};
    printPerson(obj)  // magically no error!

This is because even though obj.id may not be used inside printPerson(), obj exists outside of that function call. obj may be used in other parts of the code, and thus obj.id is still reachable and potentially usable.
Here's a useful page explaining the scenario: https://www.executeprogram.com/courses/everyday-typescript/lessons/object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties
